# What kind of problem or matrices are suitable for multigrid method?

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, linear-solver, multigrid, linear-system

For **Poisson or Convection-diffusion** equation as follows:
$$
-\Delta u=f,\qquad u|_\Omega = g.
$$
or 
$$
-\Delta u +\vec{w}.\nabla u=f,\qquad u|_\Omega = g.
$$
using FDM or FEM discretization, we can get
$$
Ax=b.
$$
I have known that **Multigrid method** is a very efficient method for these equations and I have done some numerical examples using **AMG** code bulit-in some known software, e.g., [ifiss](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/david.silvester/ifiss/download.html). Indeed, I do not know why **AMG** works so efficient (because the principles seem so complex that I cannot understand, then I just use it), from which I indeed can get an optimal reslut, i.e., iteration step independent on mesh size $h$, and CPU time is almost linear with the unknowns of the system of linear equations.

My questions is as follows:

1. why *amg* works so efficient for Poisson and C-D equations? (can you give me some simple and clear explations without detailed principles?)
2. What other else matrices are suitable for **amg** method? so far, I have just known that matrices from **Poisson and C-D** equations are best fit for **AMG**? anyone else?

Comment: These are very broad questions. Have you read some literature about the geometric multigrid method, and how it relates to the algebraic multigrid method?

Comment: Thanks Prof. Bangerth, I tried to read some but it is too complicated for me to understand it. Then my teacher told us we can just use the existing software to precondition a linear system and do not need to understand the inner principle. So I just know that for Poisson equations, it is suitable for **AMG**, and I just can use the software to solve the **Ax=b** using **AMG** preconditioner but I do not know the reasons. Thanks Prof. Can you tell me what kind of matrices are fit for **AMG**, simply?

Comment: Well, the problem is that if I explain what matrices are suitable, the explanation will not be much simpler than the one you find in the literature. It really is a complicated subject. But the short answer is that multigrid works particularly well for matrices that result from elliptic operators and that are, as a consequence, symmetric, positive definite, and sparse.